# How to improve query accuracy of Easticsearch from Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How can you improve the accuracy search results from [Elasticsearch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elasticsearch/5.2.0) using the Python wrapper? My basic example returns results, but the results are very inaccurate.

I'm running Elasticsearch 5.2 on Ubuntu 16, and I start by creating my index and adding a few documents like:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
# Document A
es.index(
    index='my-test-index',
    doc_type='text',
    body=dict(
        search_key='some specific keywords',
        weight=1.0,
        data='blah1',
    ),
)
# Document B
es.index(
    index='my-test-index',
    doc_type='text',
    body=dict(
        search_key='some other specific keywords',
        weight=1.0,
        data='blah2',
    ),
)
# Document C
es.index(
    index='my-test-index',
    doc_type='text',
    body=dict(
        search_key='some other very long text that is very different yet mentions the word specific and keywords',
        weight=1.0,
        data='blah3',
    ),
)
```

I then query it with:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='my-test-index', ignore=400)
query = 'some specific keywords'
results = es.search(
    index='my-test-index',
    body={
        'query':{
            "function_score": {
                "query": {  
                    "match": {
                        "search_key": query
                    }
                },
                "functions": [{
                    "script_score": { 
                        "script": "doc['weight'].value"
                    }
                }],
                "score_mode": "multiply"
            }
        },
    }
)
```

And although it returns all results, it returns them in the order of documents B, C, A, whereas I would expect them in the order A, B, C, because although all the documents contain all my keywords, only the first one is an exact match. I would expect C to be last because, even though it contains all my keywords, it also contains a lot of fluff I'm not explicitly searching for.

This problem compounds when I index more entries. The search returns everything that has even a single keyword from my query, and seemingly weights them all identically, causing the search results get less and less accurate the larger my index grows.

This is making Elasticsearch almost useless. Is there anyway I can fix it? Is there a problem with my `search()` call?

Comment: can you post your index configuration?

Comment: @LimH. I don't understand your question. I posted the code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your query, you can use a `match_phrase` query instead of a `match` query so that the order and proximity of the search terms get into the mix. Additionally, you can add a small `slop` in order to allow the terms to be further apart or in a different order. But documents with terms in the same order and closer apart will be ranked higher than documents with terms out of order and/or further apart. Try it out

```
            "query": {  
                "match_phrase": {
                    "search_key": query,
                    "slop": 10
                }
            },
```

Note: `slop` is a number that indicates how many ["swaps"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/slop.html) of the search terms you need to perform in order to land on the term configuration present in the document.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not reading your question more carefully and for the loaded answer below. I don't want to a stick in the mud but I think it will be clearer if you understand a bit more how Elasticsearch itself works.

Because you index your document without specifying any index and [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) configuration, Elasticsearch will use several defaults that it provides out of the box. The indexing process will first tokenize field values in your document using the [standard tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) and analyze them using [the standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) before storing them in the index. Both the standard tokenizer and analyzer work by splitting your string based on word boundary. So at the end of index time, what you have in your index for the terms in the `search_key` field are `["some", "specific", "keywords"]`, not `"some specific keywords"`.

During search time, the `match` query controls [relevance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-intro.html) using a similarity algorithm called term frequency/inverse document frequency, or TF/IDF. This algorithm is very popular in text search in general and there is a wikipedia section on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf. What's important to note here is that the more frequently your term appear in the index, the less important it is in terms of relevance. `some`, `specific`, and `keywords` appear in ALL 3 documents in your index, so as far as elasticsearch is concerned, they contribute very little to the document's relevance in your search result. Since A contains only these terms, it's like having a document containing only `the`, `an`, `a` in an English index. It won't show up as first result even if you search for `the`, `an`, `a` specifically. B ranks higher than C because B is shorter, which yields higher norm value. This norm value is explained in the relevance document. This is a bit of a speculation on my part, but I think it does work out this way if you explain the query using the [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) API.

So, back to your need, how to favor exact match over everything else? There is, of course, the [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) query as Val pointed out. Another popular method to do it, which I personally prefer, is to index the raw value in a nested field called `search_key.raw` using the `not_analyzed` option when defining your mapping: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2 and simply boost this raw value when you search.

Comment: Good intro. The second method you point out wouldn't work as it would not return documents B and C, which the OP is expecting with a lower ranking.